# Ignoring missing tables when webscraping python/pandas: mlb data

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

My question is, how can I ignore Null values in the `find.all` command if the table I'm trying to scrape isn't there?

I'm trying to teach myself webscraping and how to import the scores from yesterday's baseball games. I am a total beginner at this so apologies but my code sort of works when all 15 games were played, but if it's a day when there are less than 15 games, my code returns "IndexError: list index out of range". This is because I haven't scraped the tables in a loop. I have done them all individually (table 2, table 4 etc) as I'm pretty clueless at this.
For instance by trialing it with different URLs for different days:

https://www.espn.com/mlb/scoreboard/_/date/20190805 - 14 games - fails

https://www.espn.com/mlb/scoreboard/_/date/20190809 - 15 games - works ok

Any ideas how I could fix my code to return the correct amount of tables for the games that are up on the site on any given day and ignore missing games etc.?

Many thanks.

Well i have tried crawling through stack overflow for many hours and other online forums, like i said im a total beginner at this so i'm sure my code is horrible but I thought i would ask to see if there was an easy fix.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')

#date time stuff
now = datetime.datetime.now()- timedelta(1)
print(now)
nowFormat = now.strftime('%Y%m%d')
print(nowFormat)
str(nowFormat)

#change url
url = "https://www.espn.com/mlb/scoreboard/_/date/20190805"
url = url[:-8]
url = url+nowFormat
print(url)
driver.get(url)

#selenium to beautiful soup
soup_level1=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

#soup grabs html table
table = soup_level1.find_all('table')[1]
table2 = soup_level1.find_all('table')[3]
table3 = soup_level1.find_all('table')[5]
table4 = soup_level1.find_all('table')[7]
table5 = soup_level1.find_all('table')[9]
table6 = soup_level1.find_all('table')[11]
table7 = soup_level1.find_all('table')[13]
table8 = soup_level1.find_all('table')[15]
table9 = soup_level1.find_all('table')[17]
table10 = soup_level1.find_all('table')[19]
table11 = soup_level1.find_all('table')[21]
table12 = soup_level1.find_all('table')[23]
table13 = soup_level1.find_all('table')[25]
table14 = soup_level1.find_all('table')[27]
table15 = soup_level1.find_all('table')[29]

#give table to pandas to make a DataFrame
df1 = pd.read_html(str(table),header=0)
df1 = df1[0]
df2 = pd.read_html(str(table2),header=0)
df2 = df2[0]
df3 = pd.read_html(str(table3),header=0)
df3 = df3[0]
df4 = pd.read_html(str(table4),header=0)
df4 = df4[0]
df5= pd.read_html(str(table5),header=0)
df5 = df5[0]
df6 = pd.read_html(str(table6),header=0)
df6 = df6[0]
df7 = pd.read_html(str(table7),header=0)
df7 = df7[0]
df8 = pd.read_html(str(table8),header=0)
df8 = df8[0]
df9 = pd.read_html(str(table9),header=0)
df9 = df9[0]
df10 = pd.read_html(str(table10),header=0)
df10 = df10[0]
df11 = pd.read_html(str(table11),header=0)
df11 = df11[0]
df12 = pd.read_html(str(table12),header=0)
df12 = df12[0]
df13 = pd.read_html(str(table13),header=0)
df13 = df13[0]
df14 = pd.read_html(str(table14),header=0)
df14 = df14[0]
df15 = pd.read_html(str(table15),header=0)
df15 = df15[0]


#join dataframes together
final_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, df11, df12, df13, df14, df15], axis=0, join='outer', ignore_index=False)


#make a csv and quit
driver.quit()


print(final_df)
```

Expected the output to be something like this:

```
     1   10   11    2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  E   H   R Unnamed: 0
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  0  0  0  0  0  5  0  0   9   7        OAK
1  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   4   0        CHW
0  2.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   8   3        HOU
1  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1   8   2        BAL
0  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   7   2        NYY
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  0  3  0  0  0  2  X  0   6   8        TOR
0  3.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  2   3   4        LAA
1  1.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  2  2  5  2  4  X  0  14  16        BOS
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   7   2         KC
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  0  1  2  0  0  X  0  12   5        DET
0  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  3  0  0  2  0  1  0  13   6        WSH
1  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  3  0  0  0  0  4  0  11   7        NYM
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  0  5  0  0  0  2  0  12   8        ATL
1  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  0  0  0  1  3  0  2   9   4        MIA
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   5   2        CHC
1  0.0  NaN  NaN  2.0  0  1  0  1  1  0  X  0   6   5        CIN
0  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  1  0  1  0  2  1  0   4   5        TEX
1  1.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  0  1  0  3  0  1  2   8   6        MIL
0  0.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  0  0  5  0  0  0  0  1  14   6        CLE
1  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1   8   2        MIN
0  0.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1   7   2        PIT
1  1.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  1  0  0  0  4  X  0  10   6        STL
0  NaN  0.0  1.0  NaN  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  12   3        ARI
1  NaN  0.0  0.0  NaN  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   2   2        LAD
0  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   6   1        COL
1  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  2  0  1  0  0  4  X  1  11   7         SD
0  0.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1  0  0  0  0  0  3  1   8   5         TB
1  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  1   9   3        SEA
0  0.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  4  0  1  0  4  0  0  1  10   9        PHI
1  0.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1  1  0  3  0  0  0  1  11   6         SF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the stackoverflow, hope the below helps. I made a couple of changes:

1. Used [CSS Selectors in Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to get you the content you want
2. Used arrays to deal with variable lengths to handle different results

Good luck!

Now the code

```
soup_table_result = soup_level1.select(".inning-scoreboard > table")
table_array = []
for soup_table in soup_table_result:
    table_array.append(soup_table)

df_array = []
for t in table_array:
    df = pd.read_html(str(t), header=0)[0]
    df_array.append(df)

#join dataframes together
final_df = pd.concat(df_array, axis=0, join='outer', ignore_index=False)
```